# How To Split TestCafe Tests?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, cicd

We have around 400+ TestCafe js files and we are running these tests nightly through our CI/CD pipeline. Our problem right now is that, it consumes a lot of hours before it completes the test. What we are planning to do is to split up those tests maybe at least 4. Now my question is: How can we run the TestCafe in 4 instances with each instance runs the split tests?

For example:
Instance 1 - runs Tests #1 - #100
Instance 2 - runs Tests #101 - #200
Instance 3 - runs Tests #201 - #300
Instance 4 - runs Tests #301 - #400

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fixture or test metadata](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402831/guides/basic-guides/organize-tests#specify-test-metadata) and hen execute a different command in each instance.

For example you use fixture metadata:

```js
fixture `My fixture`
    .meta('instance', '1')

// and somewhere else:
fixture `My fixture`
    .meta('instance', '2')
```

then to run only tests within fixtures with a specific metadata:

```
$ testcafe chrome my-tests --fixture-meta instance=1
```

Or you can just group those fixture files in different directories and then run tests from only a specific directory:

```
$ testcafe chrome ./Tests/instance-one/*.js
```

Comment: Thank you @pavelsaman

I believe this will only run for one instance, right? How about running all 4 instances? Like 4 different runs or 4 different windows all at once so that we could reduce the no. of hours the test spent.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution to my own problem. I've installed this package called [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)

I added the split tests in the package.json

```
"test:split1": "testcafe chromium src-compact/SplitTest1.js --skip-js-errors",
"test:split2": "testcafe chromium src-compact/SplitTest2.js --skip-js-errors",
"test:parallel": "npm-run-all -p test:split1 test:split2"
```

And then execute it by running this command:

```
npm run test:parallel
```